# How to change the background of item in foreach embedded in list while using onMove()?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Here's my code
`

```
List {
    ForEach(timerListVM.editTimerList.timerList, id: \.self) { timer in
        AddTimerRowView(timer: timer)
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            .listRowInsets(.init(top: 4, leading: 0, bottom: 8, trailing: 0))
    }
    .onMove { indexSet, index in
        timerListVM.editTimerList.timerList.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: index)
    }
}
.listStyle(.plain)
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

`
I use listRowInsets() to put some space between item, but when I press on an item, it gets a white background and shadow.
[image]

how to hide the background and just make item wrapped by shadow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.padding(.all)` or `.padding()`.

Comment: not .padding(.all) only .padding()